# R grouping data by numeric numbers in a column

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I am trying to group data by numbers in a column, I have tried different versions of
group_by, cut, group etc but I have not been able to get it.
I have a lot of data that looks like this:

```
  position variants

     3      snv
     5      snv
    12      snv
    17      mnv
    22 deletion
    27      snv
    33      snv
    35      snv
    42      snv
    46      mnv
    50      snv
    53 deletion
    60      snv
    62      snv
    65      snv
    70      snv
```

```
variants <- c(rep("snv", 3),rep("mnv", 1),rep("deletion", 1),rep("snv", 4), "mnv", rep("snv"), "deletion", rep("snv", 4))
variants              
position = c(3, 5, 12, 17, 22, 27, 33, 35, 42, 46, 50, 53, 60, 62, 65, 70)
position
patient1 = data.frame(position, variants)
patient1
```

I would like to be able to group the data
something like this:

```
group  tally
1-10    2snv
11-20   1snv 1mnv
21-30   1deletion 1snv
31-40   2snv 
etc
```

so that i can run further downstream analysis.
And be able to change it to
groups of 1-5 or 1-2 etc.
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tidvyerse` to do a group by operation.  Create a group of ranges with `cut`, `summarise` the frequency count based on the `cut` and the 'variants', then `paste` them together in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
patient1 %>% 
   group_by(group = cut(position, breaks = c(-Inf, seq(1, 100, 
       by = 10))), variants) %>%
   summarise(n = n()) %>%
   summarise(tally = paste(n, variants, collapse=' ', sep=""))
```

NOTE: Another option is `findInterval` which does similar option as `cut` but without the `labels` as it will output numeric index

Comment: Ok im sorry i didnt see this let me see which one works best for my downstream pca analysis etc. I may need help for that too. This site is wonderful though. I really appreciate everyones help.

Comment: I think this one is better for my downstream analysis because its easier for me to split the snvs mnvs etc into integers to summarize based on the group. The other solutions may work for this as well but I am more familiar with this output. Thx again

Comment: @gdobbo thank you.  Please do follow up with me if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 2):

Here a pure R solution. Of course you can replace variables by their corresponding calls:

```
variants <- c(rep("snv", 3),rep("mnv", 1),rep("deletion", 1),rep("snv", 4), "mnv", rep("snv"), "deletion", rep("snv", 4))
position = c(3, 5, 12, 17, 22, 27, 33, 35, 42, 46, 50, 53, 60, 62, 65, 70)
patient1 = data.frame(position, variants)

labels = cut(position, seq(0, max(position), 10))
groups = split(patient1 , labels)
lapply(groups , function(x) {
  paste( table(x$variants), names(table(x$variants)), collapse = ", " )
      }
  )
```

Comment: To unilst result (lst) to data frame:  data.frame(names(lst), unlist(lst))

Comment: Sorry, I did not look at your answer when I posted mine. My answer is similar to yours. +1 to you.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can create a group column using `findInterval` making groups of every 10 positions. We can then use `aggregate` and combine the count of `variants` with the `variants` to create one string for each group.

```
patient1$group <- with(patient1, findInterval(position, (seq(0, max(position), 10))))

aggregate(variants~group, patient1, function(x) {
  tb <- table(x)
  paste(tb, names(tb), collapse = ' ')
})

#  group         variants
#1     1            2 snv
#2     2      1 mnv 1 snv
#3     3 1 deletion 1 snv
#4     4            2 snv
#5     5      1 mnv 1 snv
#6     6 1 deletion 1 snv
#7     7            3 snv
#8     8            1 snv
```